# How can I see the destination of an nserviceBus message?

Tags: nservicebus, nservicebus5, nservicebus6

In version 5 of nServiceBus I have a Behavior that keeps track of messages in flight.

In the Behavior I was able to access DeliveryOptions(SendOptions) and see the Destination Queue, in NSB 6 with the change to the Behavior I can't seem to access the destination of the message any more.

***Does anyone know of to access the destination of an outgoing message from a Behavior?***

Previous code in v5:

```
 public class PendingCommandBehavior : IBehavior<OutgoingContext>
 {
        public void Invoke(OutgoingContext context, Action next)
        {
            var sendOptions = context.DeliveryOptions as Nsb.Unicast.SendOptions;
            if (sendOptions != null && context.OutgoingMessage.MessageIntent == Nsb.MessageIntentEnum.Send)
            {
                var destinationEndpoint = sendOptions.Destination.Queue;
```

Code in v6:

```
 public class PendingCommandBehavior : Behavior<IOutgoingSendContext>
    {
        public override async Task Invoke(IOutgoingSendContext context, Func<Task> next)
        {
            // context doesn't have any destination queue information???
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `IOutgoingSendContext` is too early in the pipeline to capture the physical destination. Each outgoing send operation will go through the following contexts (in order) in NServiceBus version 6:

- `IOutgoingSendContext`
- `IOutgoingLogicalMessageContext`
- `IOutgoingPhysicalMessageContext`
- `IRoutingContext`
- `IBatchDispatchContext` (if you are sending from inside a message handler)
- `IDispatchContext`

After `IOutgoingSendContext` a routing strategy is selected but it is not converted into a physical address until after `IRoutingContext`.

For that reason, if you want to track physical addresses, the best bet is to sit in the `IDispatchContext`. This context will contain a collection of `TransportOperation`s, each of which has an `AddressTag`. This will either be an instance of `UnicastAddressTag` with a `Destination` or an instance of `MulticastAddressTag` with a `MessageType`.

Here is some code to get you started:

```
public override Task Invoke(IDispatchContext context, Func<Task> next)
{
    foreach (var operation in context.Operations)
    {
        if (operation.AddressTag is UnicastAddressTag unicastAddressTag)
        {
            var destinationEndpoint = unicastAddressTag.Destination;
        }
    }

    return next();
}
```

For more info about the NServiceBus version 6 pipeline, see [Steps, Stages and Connectors](https://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/pipeline/steps-stages-connectors) in the NServiceBus documentation.